# Very strange occurence mysql php blog

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok so the problem I'm having is very strange. I have a blog website that displays a list of posts, and i made a system to select only 10 posts at a time. and yet on the second generated page 12 results are shown (the last 2 are duplicates)

//removed url because problem solved and i dont want to get sql injected

if you goto my project above and look at the second page of posts 12 entry's are shown with the last 2 being duplicates of the 3rd(and last) page...what is going on?! they should not be able to appear because the sql LIMIT function should restrict the displayed posts to 10.

here is the code for mainpage .php

```
 <?php
session_start();
ob_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){//this works in my tests. 
  $low = 0;
  $high = 10; //this loop/if method works in conjunction with the code at the bottom of this page
  $e = 1;//starts at 1 because 1 itself is defined my default at the bottom of the page
  while($_SESSION['i'] != $e){
    $e++;

    if (isset($_REQUEST["p$e"])){
      $u = 1;
      while($u != $e){
      $u++;
        $low = $low + 10;
      $high = $high +10;
}


    }
  }}else{
    $low = 0;
    $high = 10;
  }
  ?>
<!doctype html>
<!-- AUTHOR:JOSH FAIRBANKS -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>

<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href = "addPost.php"><div id = "new">Create new post</div></a></li>
<li><a href = "mainPage.php"><div id = "veiw">Veiw posts</div></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<?php 
       $link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password' );
mysqli_select_db( $link, 'mydatabasename' );

 $results = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT LEFT(post, 575) as post FROM Users where verified = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $low , $high" ); //this displayes all the posts that have been verified
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) {
$post = $record['post'];


$count = mysqli_affected_rows( $link );  
  //ORDER BY YEAR(Date) DESC, MONTH(Date) DESC, DAY(DATE) DESC
$post .= "</td></tr></table>";
print $post;


}
 $vresults = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT post FROM Users where verified = 1" ); 
while( $vrecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $vresults ) ) {
$vpost = $vrecord['post'];


$vcount = mysqli_affected_rows( $link );  
$_SESSION['vcount'] = $vcount;
  // 
//these mirror variables arent seen and just are used to count the total amount of posts
//not just the ones on the page
}

mysqli_free_result( $results );
mysqli_close( $link );
?>
<form method = "post" action = "mainPage.php">
<table>
<tr><td>Page Number: </td><!--<td><input type = "submit" name = "p1" value = "1"></td>-->
<?php
$i = 0;
print "displaying low: $low high: $high";
for($j = 0; $j < $vcount; $j++) //modulus 
{

  if($j % 10 == 0)
  {
    $i++;
   $_SESSION['i'] = $i;
    print "<td><input type = 'submit' name ='"."p".$i. "' value = '$i'></td>"; 
  }
}  
?>
</tr>
  </table>  
</form>
</main>  
</body>
</html>
```

I know this code is a bit of a mess :p but i swear it works except for this frustrating issue. any and all help appreciated.

Comment: also as you can see @ bottom left on my site ive printed out the values being passed into the mysql limit function and they check out

Comment: oh and there are 22 posts in total but it is duplicating 2 on the second page

Comment: It should be `LIMIT ?,?` with placeholders bound in. That's expressed as *offet, count* so `10, 5` retrieves 5 records starting at #11 sequentially. Not sure why you're maintaining two variables for start/finish, but that seems to be the mistake. Normally the count is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem at $high variable... Records per page always constant. But seems that you are increment in one place.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){//this works in my tests. 
  $low = 0;
  $high = 10; //this loop/if method works in conjunction with the code at the bottom of this page
  $e = 1;//starts at 1 because 1 itself is defined my default at the bottom of the page
  while($_SESSION['i'] != $e){
    $e++;

    if (isset($_REQUEST["p$e"])){
      $u = 1;
      while($u != $e){
      $u++;
        $low = $low + 10;
      $high = 10;
}


    }
  }}else{
    $low = 0;
    $high = 10;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Wow that worked you're a genius thank you. although i'm not quite sure by what you mean by records per page is constant or how this works but it does.

Comment: `LIMIT $low , $high` - $low is offset(retrieve start from which nth record ) and $high is records per page(how many records you want for the select query). If you want to know more about mysql limit condition refer here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: Ohh okay that makes a lot more sense now ty.